# How to order a dictionary of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary of list

```
{'key':['name', value]}
```

I can't figure out how to order the dictionary by value.
For instance:

```
{'Sun': ['Sole', 3], 'Moon': ['Luna', 0], 'Mercury': ['Mercurio', 0], 'Venus': ['Venere', 16]}
```

should become

```
{'Venus': ['Venere', 16], 'Sun': ['Sole', 3], 'Moon': ['Luna', 0], 'Mercury': ['Mercurio', 0]}
```

May you please help?

Thank you.

Comment: ``{'key':['name': value]}`` did you mean ``{'key':['name', value]}``?

Comment: Try this - ```dict(sorted(l.items(), key= lambda x: -x[1][1]))```

Comment: Indeed is {'key':['name', value]}, my apologies

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, use lambda

```
dct = {'Sun': ['Sole', 3], 'Moon': ['Luna', 0], 'Mercury': ['Mercurio', 0], 'Venus': ['Venere', 16]}
res = {k:v for k,v in sorted(dct.items(), key = lambda x:x[1][1], reverse=True)}
```